# How to turn healpy region into 2d array?

Tags: astronomy, healpy

Basically all I want is the functionally of hp.cartview, but I don't want my machine to waste memory plotting the actual map every single time I call the cartview function. How can I obtain a cartesian projection in healpy **in the form of a 2d array** without having to plot the projection every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me point out that [reproject](https://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/healpix.html) might be a better tool for the job.

You can build a [WCS](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/wcs/) object or a FITS header and then reproject your HEALPix map onto that, and subsequently plot it with [wcsaxes](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/visualization/wcsaxes/), which gives you full support for real-world coordinate pixels (instead of pixel coordinates only).

If you really want to use healpy for these `cartview` cutouts instead, you can use the underlying `healpy.projector.CartesianProj` class:

```py
from functools import partial

import healpy as hp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Build a map
nside = 64
npix = hp.nside2npix(nside)
hpxmap = np.arange(npix)

# Get the cutout via a cartesian projection
lonra = [30, 40]
latra = [-10, 10]

proj = hp.projector.CartesianProj(
    lonra=lonra, latra=latra,
    coord='G',
    xsize=n_pixels, ysize=n_pixels)
reproj_im = proj.projmap(hpxmap, vec2pix_func=partial(hp.vec2pix, nside))

# Plot the cutout
plt.imshow(reproj_im, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest')
```

Good luck, let me know if you have any follow-up questions!

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Comment: @Daniel Lenz: How do you handle cases where parts of the patch would cross over the pole and fall on the other side? If it's a point I guess one would have
 - new lattitude = 180 - old lattitude
 - new longitude = 180 + old longitude
But how does one specify new lonra and latra in that case?